# How to compress python .exe file size

Tags: python, exe

I have converted python file to exe using [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/)
But the size of .exe is 800mb, is there any way I can reduce its size?

Comment: can you paste a minimal reproduciable code that led to so large installer?

Comment: @LeiYang I have used sklearn library for Linear Regression.

Comment: can you check the (compressed) directory size of sklearn library module?

Answer (score 2):

**Using Pyinstaller**

The `--onefile` flag with pyinstaller (e.g., `pyinstaller myprogram.py --onefile` or `pyinstaller myprogram.py -F` puts everything in just a single executable, including all the code of all your installed dependencies, even if you're using just one function from them. That's a lot!

The `--onedir` or `-D` flag instead puts the those dependencies in a directory that's packaged alongside your compiled code. It tends to reduce the size of the .exe file considerably.

**But still, I wouldn't recommend using Pyinstaller.** Having experimented with it extensively, I've found that execution time is incredibly slow on machines that don't already have a Python-friendly environment. (Most of the slow execution time comes from loading those dependencies.)

**Using cx_Freeze**

For the executables that I build for my department, I use [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to build an installer or a disk image.

To do so, all you have to do is [write a setup script](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_script.html) and then call `py setup.py bdist_msi` (Windows) or `py setup.py dbist_dmg` (Linux).

The resulting installer will be relatively small and, once it's installed, it will execute much faster than any of the Pyinstaller options I've seen.